# How to Handle Variant in SCSS using BEM Methodology

Tags: html, css, sass, bem

I'm  trying to figure out this stupid yet annoying issue that I face up with  BEM. Currently for my application, I follow the BEM methodology for  creating UI Elements. For instance :

```
<div class="card">
    <h2 class="card__title">Sample Title </h2>
    <h3 class="card__subtitle"> Sub Title </h3>
    <button class="card__action"> Action Button </button>
</div>
```

The scss for this will be :

```
.card{
     &__title{color:red}
     &__subtitle{color:violet}
     &__subtitle{bakground:black}
}
```

Now if I need to add a new variant of the card, I will be adding it as "card--modifier".

```
.card{
    &--variant{background-color:white}
    &__title{color:red}
    &__subtitle{color:violet}
    &__subtitle{bakground:black}
}
```

Now, **without breaking this nesting in scss**, how can I modify the properties of child under the variant ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In situations like this I don't make a big fuss about repeating a classname or two.

If in case of `card--variant` you want for example the `card__title` to have a blue font color, you could just add the necessairy changes at the end of your rules (order is important, keep your specifity low and add special cases at the end)

```
.card {
   &__title { color: red; }
   &__subtitle { color: violet; }
   &__action { background-color: black; }

   &--variant {
       .card__title { color: blue; }
   }
}
```

If for some reason you adamantly don't want to duplicate a name, you can capture the block-level name in a variable and use string interpolation:

```
.card {
   $block: &;
   &__title { color: red; }
   &__subtitle { color: violet; }
   &__action { background-color: black; }

   &--variant {
       .#{$block}__title { color: blue; }
   }
}
```